# Django Debug Toolbar unexpected behaviour

Tags: python, django, debugging, serialization, django-debug-toolbar

I have defined two serializers for a model, `ListingSerializer` and `DetailedSerializer`.
Also, there is a static function `get_people_count()` defined in both serializers as below:

```
@staticmethod
def get_people_count(obj):
  #some code
```

When using Django Debug toolbar, `get_people_count()` of `ListingSerializer` is called instead of `DetailedSerializer`'s even though `DetailedSerializer` is returned in overridden `get_serializer_class()`. However, this problem doesn't occur when using Postman. Debug toolbar is updated to 1.11 version, still this issue is occuring.

Comment: can you post both the codes fully??